# Want to learn how to use value of textbox to set the value of another textbox (automatically)

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g, textbox

I got tired working on that part of code for 3 days and searching on the internet please I need help to **learn\ know HOW TO** use auto complete `textbox1` and use its value to set the value of `textbox2` and `textbox3` below code I got from searching on the internet and collection random information from different posts.

According to what I get that the fastest way...

```
public class PopulateProduct
{
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct> dict = new Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct>();

public void load()
{
    string connstr = "user id=user;password=pwd";
    string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE 
                              from products";

    AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dict.Add((string)dr["PRODUCT_ID"],
                    new PopulateProduct()
                    {
                        ProductDesc = (string)dr["DESCRIPTION"],
                        UnitPrice = (decimal)dr["UNIT_PRICE"]
                    });
                autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Now on the `textbox1` where suggestion form oracle database should appear no suggestion appears and no data are assigned to `textbox2` and `textbox3`

```
private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text)) 
    {
        TB_PRODUCTS_DESC.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].ProductDesc;
        TB_UNIT_PRICE.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].UnitPrice.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? In which part you need help?

Comment: @RezaAghaei At text changed event as i said when textchaned the suggestion should appear according to the input then when i choose the vale of textbox1 i need to assigne value for textbox2 and textbox3 but thats not happen

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of using the TextChanged event particularly on an autocomplete textbox to trigger other actions, as I never have been able to figure out when the autocompleted value shows up in the text.  I prefer to have the user leave the box completely when I know that the value has been chosen.  Even if this doesn't work for you, try putting your code in the Leave event and see if it works.  If it does then your problem is probably that the TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text does not contain the autocompleted value.